# Excel VBA Macro - Pt2

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Trying to restrict a user from selecting from anything in 3 columns with a **data validation list**

Target Range: (three columns L:N) i.e. L3, M3, N3 up to L40, M40, N40.

Unless a user first populates a field in Column U

Target Range: U3-U40

I've tried searching how to lock cell selection unless a corresponding cell is selected for the last few days to no avail. Think the issue is because the target cells aren't actually having a value entered and instead are using a list from conditional formatting.

EDIT: Not sure if I made this clear or not but each line should work independently of the other i.e. want to lock L3, M3 and N3 unless U3 is populated, same goes for L4,M4 and N4 unless U4 is populated.. etc

Thanks!
Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

In the code module of the sheet you wish to protect, please enter the following...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Shield
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Shield
    If Len(Me.[u5]) Then Me.Unprotect '<-- change 'u5' to the cell in column U that unlocks
End Sub

Sub Shield()
    With Me
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Locked = False
        .[L3:n40].Locked = True
        .Protect , 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Update

The above code works, keying off just one cell `U5` to control whether the entire range `L3:N40` is locked or not.

Now I understand that you want each row of `L3:N40` to be independently locked/unlocked based on whether the same row of range `U3:U40` has a value.

The following code works for this new scenario...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Shield
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Shield
End Sub

Sub Shield()
    Dim c
    With Me
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Locked = False
        For Each c In .[u3:u40]
            If Len(c) = 0 Then c.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 3).Locked = True
        Next
        .Protect , 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Andy, if this works for you, please accept the answer. I noticed that  you didn't do that on your first question.

Comment: Hi - this still didn't work... Note: Not sure if I didn't make this clear or not but each line should work independantly of the other i.e. want to lock L3, M3 and N3 unless U3 is populated, same goes for L4,M4 and N4 unless U4 is populated.. etc